# WPF user control with a property of type Enum

Tags: wpf, textbox, enums

I have a `UserControl` called `InputSensitiveTextBox` that inherits from `TextBox`. It has a property I define called `CurrentInputType`, which is of type `MyControlsNamespace.SupportedInputTypes` (with values `Keyboard`, `Mouse`, `Touchpad`, `VirtualKey`).  I need to have this property be set in Xaml just like I might set `HorizontalAlignment` or `ScrollbarVisibility` as such:

```
MyControlsNamespace.InputSensitiveTextBox Background="Black" CurrentInputType="Keyboard"
```

Please advise :)

Comment: Have you tried just typing in the enumeration value as you would in HorizontalAlignment/ScrollbarVisibility? Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes.  It says it can't convert a string to the enum value, as I expected. :/

Comment: Why is `MyControlsNamespace` in your example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Static` markup extension to reference your enumeration in xaml and you also need to add its namespace to your namespace declarations.

```
xmlns:MyControlsNamespace ="clr-namespace:MyControlsNamespace"

<MyControlsNamespace:InputSensitiveTextBox 
    CurrentInputType="{x:Static MyControlsNamespace:SupportedInputTypes.Keyboard}"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your CurrentInputType a dependency property?

If not here is the code for it to replace your old property:

```
public SupportedInputTypes CurrentInputType
{
    get { return (SupportedInputTypes)GetValue(CurrentInputTypeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentInputTypeProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CurrentInputType.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentInputTypeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentInputType", typeof(SupportedInputTypes), typeof(InputSensitiveTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(SupportedInputTypes.Keyboard));
```

In the PropertyMetadata you define your default..

Hope this fixes your problem!

Comment: well the issue is that the markup doesn't know what a SupportedInputTypes type is.  Not sure that a dependancy property will fix that...

Comment: You can always set the value in xaml with the Static extension of course.. {x:Static local:SupportedInputTypes.Keyboard} .. Not the solution you want, but it works..