# UserControl Properties just working properly when they're strings

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to create an UserControl for a UWP Project where I want to have an indicator of the unit the user is working with.

To achieve that I've created an enum and defined the types of units the control will handle as in the following example:

```
 public static class UnitEnum
 {
    public enum Unit
    {
        Size,
        Weight,
        Currency,
        Percentage
    }
 }
```

Then I've created the property `ValueUnit` on my UserControl which should be set when adding that control to the UI as following:

```
<usercontrols:NumericBox ValueUnit="Currency"/>
<usercontrols:NumericBox ValueUnit="Percentage"/>
<usercontrols:NumericBox ValueUnit="Size"/>
<usercontrols:NumericBox ValueUnit="Weight"/>
```

Inside the UserContol I have a switch case where the indicator string changes to match the system default unit for that data type (Ex: Currency = €, Size = M (from meters)) as following:

```
switch (ValueUnit)
{
        case Unit.Currency:
             UnitSymbol = System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol;
             break;
    
        case Unit.Percentage:
             UnitSymbol = "%";
             break;
        
        case Unit.Size:
             if (System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric) UnitSymbol = "m";
             break;
    
        case Unit.Weight:
             if (System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric) UnitSymbol = "Kg";
             break;
   }
```

Then I Bind the `UnitSymbol` to the correspondent TextBlock:

```
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind UnitSymbol}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5"/>
```

But when running it always shows me the symbol that corresponds to the first value of the enum (in this case size), even when I've set the `ValueUnit` to any other value in the XAML.

Example:

[image: Each NumericTextBox has its an different ValueUnit]

**Update 1**

I've added a name to the `UserControl` with `ValueUnit == Currency` as shown here:

```
<usercontrols:NumericBox ValueUnit="Currency" x:Name="CurrencyBox"/>
```

And in the code-behind I've added the following line and placed a breakpoint:

```
    var a = CurrencyBox.ValueUnit;
```

When the app stops on that line `a = Size`, `CurrencyBox.ValueUnit = Currency`, both derived from `Enums.UnitEnum.Unit`, there when advancing the execution `a` changes to `Currency` too but in the end it still shows me the size symbol (m).

**Update 2**

After some testing I've found that any of the other properties in the `UserControl` aren't working, just the ones that get `Strings`.

Example:

```
<usercontrols:NumericBox Header="Teste" ValueUnit="Currency" HasCalc="True" x:Name="CurrencyBox"/>
```

- `Header` (that's is a `string`) is working. ✅
- `ValueUnit` (that's a `Unit` from my `UnitEnum`) isn't working ❌
- `HasCalc` (that's a normal `bool`) isn't working ❌

Props in the UserControl code-behind:

```
 public string Header { get; set; }
 public Unit ValueUnit { get; set; }
 public bool HasCalc { get; set; }
```

Also, the property `UnitSymbol` (`string`) is working since the value in it is shown.

Comment: I do not think `ValueUnit="Currency"` is valid. `ValueUnit="Unit.Currency"` sounds much more like it. Keep in mind that Enums are collections of compile time constants. Usually *integer* compile time constants. And given no valid values, the System usually has to default to something.

Comment: I am not certain that you can directly set the enum value like that on a property. How have you declared the property? In [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213223/wpf-user-control-with-a-property-of-type-enum) you have to do some workarounds - maybe it's the same for UWP.

Comment: @fredrik         ```public Unit ValueUnit { get; set; } ```

Comment: Try with the `{x:Static ..}` as in WPF and see if that works.

Comment: @Christopher  I don't know if that's true because IntelliSense recognizes the values like that on the XAML when I introduce the value, but ill try it.

Comment: @Cristopher Already tried that but the IntelliSense only recognizes Currency, Weight, Size and Percentage as valid values for that field.

Comment: Where is this switch located in your user control?

Comment: @fredrik On the constructor.

Comment: You can't have this in the constructor - UWP will not have set the value of the property yet. You have to move it to function that is called on rendering.

Comment: Or write a custom getter for UnitSymbol that checks ValueUnit "live" on each call. Property Changed notification is also usable for this - but maybe overkill if you don't expect the value to change after initialization is complete.

Comment: Why can't I use other properties than strings like `bool` when I call the `UserControl` on the xaml like on this sample: `<usercontrols:NumericBox Header="Teste" ValueUnit="Currency" HasCalc="True" x:Name="CurrencyBox"/>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236059/discussion-between-david-simoes-and-fredrik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce your issue using the code you posted. The problem might be related to `DataBinding`. The default binding mode of X:bind is onetime which means it won't change once the binding is created.

The main thing I changed is to use Binding instead of X:Bind.

For example in UserControl:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock x:Name="MyTextBlock" Text="{Binding UnitSymbol,Mode=OneWay}"/>
    <Button Content="{Binding Header,Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding HasCalc,Mode=OneWay}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And in the code-behind I have:

```
 public TestUserControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += TestUserControl_Loaded;
    }

    private void TestUserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (ValueUnit)
        {
            case UnitEnum.Unit.Currency:
                UnitSymbol = System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol;
                break;

            case UnitEnum.Unit.Percentage:
                UnitSymbol = "%";
                break;

            case UnitEnum.Unit.Size:
                if (System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric) UnitSymbol = "m";
                break;

            case UnitEnum.Unit.Weight:
                if (System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.IsMetric) UnitSymbol = "Kg";
                break;
        }
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Then I'm calling it from the MainPage like this:

```
  <local:TestUserControl HasCalc="False" ValueUnit="Percentage" Header="Yes"/>
```

And the result looks like this:
[image]

Since it's a very simple test, if you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you're answer, the problem here was that I implemented the login on the constructor and not in the `Loaded()` event. There I just needed to change from x:Bind to Binding on the TextBlock that shows the unit and set it to two way.

Answer (score 2):

`ValueUnit="Currency"` sets ValueUnit to the string "Currency" and not to a value in `UnitEnum`. Then, when you are in your switch statement, nothing matches and the default value of 0 is returned.

To get around this, you can change your `case` conditions to use the `.ToString()` method, like this:

```
case Unit.Currency.ToString():
       UnitSymbol = System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol;
             break;
```

Comment: He could also parse the value into an enum and then switch over it - which would have the added value of being able to warn of cases that have not been handled.

Comment: @RobJarvis Thank you for you're help but when I apply the ```.ToString()``` method the VisualStudiu tells me that the value does not exists in the Enum.

Comment: Admittedly, @fredrik, my solution is a bit hacky and ignores best practices. It is a workaround which invites a better and more robust solution such as yours.

Comment: To apply his solution you would have to change the property into a string as well - not the enum

Comment: Why can't I use other properties than `strings` like `bool` when I call the `UserControl` on the xaml like on this sample: `<usercontrols:NumericBox Header="Teste" ValueUnit="Currency" HasCalc="True" x:Name="CurrencyBox"/>`